# How can I resize an NSTextField to fit the text that it holds?

Tags: cocoa, text, measurement, nstextfield

I'm using an `NSTextField` to display lines of text that will be printed on a printer with a variable paper size (the printer prints to a spool, which is cut to the appropriate length when the job is done).

I can generate the text no problem, but I need to know how big to make the `NSTextField` (vertically) so that it exactly contains all of the lines of text. Is there an easy way of going about this?

The text is prepared as an `NSAttributedString`, and the lines are all of a fixed width (no wrapping), if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a great category on NSString/NSAttributedString by Jerry Krinock which allows you to calculate the height of text based on its width and vice versa:

http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html

I've used this often and it works very well indeed.